# JButton ActionListener Integration Issue

Tags: java, swing, html-parsing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am relatively new to Java and recently I have been working on a GUI based html parser. 
The interface is simple, consisting of:

1. `JTextField` for entering a search term
2. `JButton` b1 to initiate the search
3. `JButton` b2 to exit
4. `JButton` b3 to display an URL in the browser using cmd prmt.

The problem arises with b3. 
Here is a code sample:

```
while (mstyle2.find()) 
{
    String s=mstyle2.group(0);
    String pattern = "(?i)(<cite.*?>)(.+?)(</cite>)";
    String updated = s.replaceAll(pattern, "$2"); 
    String pattern2 = "(?i)(<b>)(.+?)(</b>)";
    String updated2 = updated.replaceAll(pattern2, "$2"); 
    String pattern3 = "(http://)";
    boolean c=true;
    String updated32 = updated2.replaceAll(pattern3, ""); 
    String pattern32 = "(https://)";
    final String updated3 = updated32.replaceAll(pattern32,""); 

    try {
        URL url2 = new URL("http://"+updated3);
        URLConnection conne = url2.openConnection();
        conne.connect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        c=false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        c=false;//checks validity of url 
    }

    if(c) {
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start http://"+updated3);
    }
}
```

The idea is that the following command line should only be executed when b3 is pressed. Otherwise the loop will not execute, and remain in that line until the button is pressed.

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start http://"+updated3);
```

However, I cannot find any viable way to properly implement the `ActionListener` method in order to make this possible.

In most of my tries, once b3 is pressed, all link open at once (thus beating the purpose of the b3) and not one by one with every click of b3.

Comment: *"`JButton` b3 to display an URL in the browser using cmd prmt."*  Use [`Desktop.browse(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) instead.  It will be a lot more robust (& cross-platform).

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

`JButton`s has a method called `addActionListener()`. This method allows you to attach a runnable to a button, so the code is only called when it is clicked.

```
 b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
           // Your code here!
      }
 });
```

**What is this doing?**

Well this is adding a new `ActionListener` object to your button. However, `ActionListener` has an abstract method, `actionPeformed` that needs an implementation. You are simply providing the code in the constructor.

Comment: Also consider [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Comment: yes,I have tried this method as well - but again, this problem arises -- In most of my tries, once b3 is pressed, all link open at once (thus beating the purpose of the b3) and not one by one with every click of b3.

Basically it executes all urls at once instead of in a per click fashion. Also, this method does not prevent the entire loop from executing despite the button not being clicked.

Comment: Chris - unfortunately , the method is not working within a loop in the manner you stated , any help please?

Comment: What is the code you're putting into the `actionPerformed` method?